# Javascript alert still shows after condition changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a web page where one must select an input from a list and then hit a button which takes to you a new page based on that selection.  If nothing from the list is selected and this button is pressed, I want the user to be alerted that they must select from the list before proceeding.

So my initial HTML has a blank href:`<a id="Button" href="">Start</a>`

Then I add this href via js after list selection:

```
choice.mousedown(function(){
    if (this.data('fullname')=='X'){
           document.getElementById('Button').href = '/newpageX';}}
```

This all works fine and adds the href to the button exactly as desired.  The problem comes when I next try to add the alert when the href is still emtpy.  So after the js code above, in order to alert the user if this href is still blank (ie nothing chosen from list) and they hit the button, I added a check as follows (using jquery):

```
document.getElementById('Button').onclick = function () {
    if ($('Button').attr('href') === undefined) {
        alert('Please select an option from list above');}}
```

This does seem to work fine when nothing has been selected, but if a user does select something from list, this alert **still shows** anyway before it then correctly proceeds to the new page based on list selection (newpageX)!  This is my main problem.  So it's as if the condition of the href (defined/undefined) isn't re-checked via the jquery if statement after the href is defined via the list choice - and beause of this the alert still shows anyway.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I prevent the alert from showing if in fact the href is now defined based on the list selection?  Is there a better overall strategy here?

Also, separately - when href is in fact empty and the button is pushed, after one hits 'ok' on the alert, the page is reloaded.  I don't believe this is necessary - how can I just have the alert show, but not reload the page?  I tried to add 'return false;' after the if statement, but then it won't proceed to new page when a list selection is made.

Thanks in advance for any assistance guys...

Comment: A good start would be to decide to use either `jQuery` or `Vanilla Javascript`. There's no reason to mix up both.

Comment: It's `$('#Button')`

Comment: `$('Button')` is part of your problem - you want `$('#Button')`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - I added the # and now the alert doesn't show at all (the page just reloads)... hmmmm... sorry for my lack of knowledge here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the comments above gave me part of the answer, but the complete solution was to change the first line of jquery if statement to:

```
if ($('#Button').attr('href') == '') {
```

So I needed to add the # before Button, but also change from `=== undefined` to `== ''`

Just adding the # before Button without changing the second part killed the alert altogether.  I was then also able to add `return false;` after the alert to prevent the page from reloading upon empty button click.